# Using geoloqi for developers, Is my app code available to geoloqi team?

Tags: xcode, geolocation

I would like to use Real-time Location Tracking geoloqi platform for developers, I didn't find any statement regarding this the developer app code privacy in geoloqi website. I would like to make sure that my application code privacy is kept and the code is not available to anyone including the geoloqi developers team. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the source code to your application will not be visible to the Geoloqi team. You are free to create a closed-source app that uses our SDK and API without sharing the source code with anyone.